# Download a large file in background only on WiFi

Tags: java, android, download, android-service, android-wifi

So what I'm trying to achieve is creating a service that downloads a large (~200 MB) file to the app's internal directory. It should resume (not restart) when it got canceled and automatically resume after a system reboot. It should sometimes (as written in a propeties file) only download using WiFi connection.

To do so I created an `IntentService` (is that a suitable solution?) that gets started by an `Frgament`'s UI or by a `BroadcastReceiver` (after boot-up):

```
@Override
     public void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
            c.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
            c.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                            WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
            receiver.onReceive(null, null); // To start the download the first time
}
```

The last line calls a `BroadcastReceiver` that handles the download process. This is the way I tried to make sure that there is only one ongoing download at a time:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean allowed = isConnectionAllowed();

        if (allowed && !thread.isAlive()) {

            thread.start();

        } else if (allowed && thread.isAlive()) {

            thread.notify(); // Can this cause any problems in this  case?

        } else if (!allowed && thread.isAlive()) {

            try {

                thread.wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if (StartActivity.DEV_MODE)
                    Log.i(StartActivity.LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And the download itselv runs in a seperate `Thread`.

```
private Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void run() {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        RandomAccessFile output = null;

        try {

            long already_downloaded = 0;

            URL url = new URL(getSource());
            File outputFileCache = new File(getDestination());
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (outputFileCache.exists()) {
                connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="
                        + outputFileCache.length() + "-");
            }

            connection.setConnectTimeout(14000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2)
                throw new Exception("Invalid response code!");

            else {
                String connectionField = connection
                        .getHeaderField("content-range");

                if (connectionField != null) {
                    String[] connectionRanges = connectionField.substring(
                            "bytes=".length()).split("-");
                    already_downloaded = Long.valueOf(connectionRanges[0]);
                }

                if (connectionField == null && outputFileCache.exists())
                    outputFileCache.delete();

                long fileLength = connection.getContentLength()
                        + already_downloaded;
                input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                output = new RandomAccessFile(outputFileCache, "rw");
                output.seek(already_downloaded);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count = 0;
                int progress = 0;
                int progress_last_value = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1
                        && progress != 100) {
                    already_downloaded += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                    progress = (int) ((already_downloaded * 100) / fileLength);
                    if (progress != progress_last_value) {
                                // Update notification
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            if (StartActivity.DEV_MODE)
                Log.i(StartActivity.LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (StartActivity.DEV_MODE)
                Log.i(StartActivity.LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (StartActivity.DEV_MODE)
                Log.i(StartActivity.LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));

        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (StartActivity.DEV_MODE)
                    Log.i(StartActivity.LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }

        // notify the Fragment using a `LocalBroadcast`.
    }
};
```

And to make sure that the WiFi connection ist kept alive, I use the `WifiLock` class.

Note: I shortened the code in a few cases but I already managed to write that code.

So I'm not sure whether this is a good solution for my problem:

- Should I use an `IntentService` or a normal `Service` for that?
- Is that solution using a `Thread` a good one and will it work?

  - Won't the `HttpURLConnection` expire?
  - Can I access the Thread that way? (referres to `wait()` and `notify()`)

I know this is a lot of code but it was the closest I could get. I hope someone knows a solution for that becuase I couldn't find anything usful on that topic ("only download while WiFi in ON") using Google and StackOverflow.

Thanks in advance,
Felix

(Comment if you need the whole `Class`)

Comment: OK. 'viewed: 32 times'. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any information missing? Is it off-topic? Please comment for feedback. Any suggestions? Any ideas?

Comment: @ felixd: Is this problem solved?

Comment: @HarishKoona Unfortunately, not yet. Do you have a concept? I might start a bouty some time in the future but I don't have that much reputation for now.